# React good practise to render one screen inside another when one screen component needs almost everything from another screen component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react native and I have (among others) 2 screens. **SearchScreen Component and ReportScreen Component.** In my ReportScreen I basically need everything from SearchScreen (I render the search input field and the autocomplete component for the search suggestions plus all the functions from my component) except the SearchResults, as in my report component I will 1st search , and 2nd report something make a post request. I could have a conditional for rendering the searchResults and then render searchscreen inside reportScreen, but that seems bad practise. I cant see how I can refactor it and would love to get some advise what to do in such situation based on good practise. Thank you!!

```
const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    // setting state...

    const fetchData = async () => {...};
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    const updateSearch = item => {...}
    const submitSearch = async (id) => {...}
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Search //component with search input bar
                display={display}
                setDisplay={setDisplay}
                searchInput={searchInput}
                onSearchInputChange={(input) => setSearchInput(input)}
                showCancelIcon={showCancelIcon}
                handleShowCancelIcon={(input) => setShowCancelIcon(input)}
                />
            <AutoComplete
                display={display}
                setDisplay={setDisplay}
                searchInput={searchInput}
                submitSearch={submitSearch}
                onSearchInputChange={updateSearch}
                data={data}
            />
                <SearchResult
                    searchResult={searchResult}
                    submitNewSearch={submitSearch}
                />
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a HOC(Higher Order Component) that will implement the common items of your components.

Refer to this link to know more about HOC: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: but HOC are more for when components share same logic but render different stuff or not? mine is rendering exactly same except the searchResults component. Plus HOC should be pure functions. My code makes api requests. Also arent HOC indirectly replaced now with custom hooks?